# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `[]' for nil:NilClass when iterate array of files

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-upload, paperclip, forms

I have a form where i generate particular set of user input fields based on how many times the user want to generate

**example:**

If the user give 2 as input then a piece of javascript will generate tow set of same input fields

**Workflow example:**

How many users: 2

//Generated fields

Enter user 1 information

- Name:
- Address:
- Photo:

Enter user 2 information

- Name:
- Address:
- Photo:

I have set the field names  as array

```
<input type="text" name="name[]" >
<input type="text" name="address[]" >
<input type="file" name="photo[]" >
<input type="hidden" name="user_count" value="count">
```

In my controller when the loop reaches the photo field it throws error `undefined method [] for nil:NilClass`

```
      @current_user = 0
      @number_of_users = params[:user_count].to_i 

      until @curret_field > (@number_of_users-1)  do  
        @user=User.new
        @user.name=params[:name][@current_user]
        @user.address=params[:address][@current_user]
        @user.photo=params[:photo][@current_user]
      end
```

Comment: This means that the `params` Hash doesn't contain the key `photo`

Comment: This error is thrown only when the photo field left blank, and submitted.

Comment: This code will break if we submit the form with a `params[:user_count]` higher than the actual number of inputs

Comment: You are correct @MrYoshiji, i have already validated  the input in my javascript and it will generate  set of same input fields only the input value is less then 20 .

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.try` method to test which param is missing:

```
params[:name].try(:[], @current_user) # returns nil if can't access to it
```

But I would change my params keys/values mapping to the following:

```
@users.each_with_index do |user, i|
  text_field_tag "users[#{i}]name"
  text_field_tag "users[#{i}]address"
  file_field_tag "users[#{i}]photo"
end
```

And loop in the controller like this:

```
params[:users].each do |user_params|
  User.new(user_params)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply MrYoshiji, This error is thrown only when the photo field left blank, and submitted. –

Comment: You can use `params[:photo].try(:[], @current_user)` then